# New SSL Certificate for each client deployment?

Tags: ssl, deployment, jboss, https, ssl-certificate

**Context:**

I have an application that is deployed to each client as a Virtual Machine. The latter is installed by the clients wherever they want (I don't necessarily know the final domain). The application comprises an JBoss Web Server that provides access to a configuration page, protected by SSL. Right now the server is using a self signed Certificate. However, I want the browsers to stop showing the warning messages associated to self signed certs. Moreover, I provide a free version of the application that has basic functionality.

**Question:**

For cases where the client is using a free version (and me wanting to reduce costs), what is the best approach when using a SSL cert, and not knowing the final domain (most of the time)?

- It is acceptable to use a self-signing cert? If so, a different one
  per client install?
- Is it best to issue a new cert (maybe a free one) for each
  deployment?
- Is is acceptable to use the same cert, signed by a proper CA, on all
  of the deployment VMs?
- A *completely* different approach?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is acceptable to use a self-signing cert? If so, a different one per client install?

Ask your clients. Will they put up with a browser warning? or not?

> Is it best to issue a new cert (maybe a free one) for each deployment?

It is best for the *client* to acquire *his own* SSL certificate. You can't do that for him. Nobody can.

> Is is acceptable to use the same cert, signed by a proper CA, on all of the deployment VMs?

No, it entirely defeats the purpose. The certificate and the private key it wraps are supposed to ***uniquely*** identify the holder.

> A completely different approach?

Handball the whole megillah to the clients. Self-identification is their problem, not yours.